# Basic Scheme- functional programming

Tags: string, functional-programming, scheme

I want to write a function that **scores the alignment of two strings according to the scoring scheme specified below**.

So this function will take `two or more characters` and return an `integer`.

```
Match Type and Points  
Match          2  
Mismatch      -1  
Space-match   -2  

So 
"h" "h"     gives you 2  
"h" "k"      gives you      -1  
"h" "_"      gives you      -2

(define (char-scorer char1 char2)  
  (cond ((char=? char1 char2) 2) 
    ((or (char=? char1 #\_ ) (char=? #\_ char2)) -2)
    (else -1)))  

(define (alignment-score s1 s2)    
  (define min-length (min (string-length s1) (string-length s2)))
  (let loop ((score 0) (index 0))
    (if (= index min-length) 
        score
        (loop (+ score (char-scorer (string-ref s1 index)
                                    (string-ref s2 index)))

          (+ index 1)))))
```

But when I tried using (alignment-score-not-tail "Hello" "_ _low"), which is suppose to give me -4, but i get -1

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Rethink it a bit. If your "if" condition does not hold, you already know that the characters are not equal. But what do you need to test after that? Also, your syntax needs a bit of editing: `(define (scorer char1 char2) (if (= char1 char2) 2`...if the left-paren is not proceeded by a quote mark, it represents the start of a procedure.

Comment: If they not equal, then they either have to be different, or the one could possibly be an underscore, but confused on how to write it?

Comment: Yes, you need to test whether the second character is an underscore (I am assuming the order of the characters matters). So you can do that with another `if` inside the `else` part of the first `if`, right?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. Think about the order of your conditions, though. Any time the first condition (equality of characters) fails, `(not (equal? char1 char2))` will succeed, which means anything you put after that is never reached! By the way, `=` is only for numeric values, not for characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your latest `string-scorer`, I would do the following:

```
(define (char-scorer char1 char2)  
  (cond 
    ((char=? char1 char2) 2) 
    ((or (char=? #\_ char1) (char=? #\_ char2)) -2)
    (else -1)))  

(define (alignment-score-not-tail string1 string2)
  (apply + (map char-scorer (string->list string1) (string->list string2))))
```

then

```
> (alignment-score-not-tail "Hello" "__low")
-4
```

Some details:

1. I chose to compare chars, not one-letter strings. This comes in handy later when using `string->list`. Hence also the use of `char=?` which is more specific than `equal?`.
2. I convert the strings to lists, for example `(string->list "Hello")` is `'(#\H #\e #\l #\l #\o)`.
3. If you `map` your char comparison to the 2 strings converted to lists, you get a list with the individual results (in your example, `'(-2 -2 2 -1 -1)`.
4. Now you just have to add all these numbers, that's what `apply +` does. Not the best solution, but works for small lists.

Alternatively, if this is supposed to be a non tail-recursive procedure, you could do the following:

```
(define (alignment-score-not-tail string1 string2)
  (define (helper lst1 lst2)
    (if (or (null? lst1) (null? lst2))
        0
        (+ (char-scorer (car lst1) (car lst2)) (helper (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))))
  (helper (string->list string1) (string->list string2)))
```

and transforming to a tail-recusive one could be done as follows:

```
(define (alignment-score-tail string1 string2)
  (define (helper lst1 lst2 result)
    (if (or (null? lst1) (null? lst2))
        result
        (helper (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2) (+ result (char-scorer (car lst1) (car lst2))))))
  (helper (string->list string1) (string->list string2) 0))
```

Comment: I actually want it to accept 1-letter strings, not chars, sorry

Comment: So I have this: (define (string-scorer string1 string2)
    (cond (((equal? string1 #\_ )(equal? #\_ string2))-2)
          ((equal? string1 string2) 2)
          (not(equal? (string1 string2))-1)
          (else 0)))

Comment: Did you see my update? It works for strings of different lengths.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to refresh. I'm actually just trying to fit in my method of (define (alignment-score-not-tail string_one string_two)
(if (and (not (= (string-length string_one) 0))
(not (= (string-length string_two) 0)))
(+ (char-scorer (string-ref string_one 0)
(string-ref string_two 0))
(alignment-score-not-tail
(substring string_one 1 (string-length string_one))
(substring string_two 1 (string-length string_two))
)
)
0)
) So that I can then change this to be tail-recursive though, because that's what's expected from the Question. I need to be painfully precise, sorry

Comment: Ok wait, I've edited my version again, trying a tail-recursive approach, please have a look at that

Comment: I would suggest having a look at my procedures. I just added a tail-recursive one, and I'll stop here. Your approach with length and stuff is not idiomatic, and mine are way more concise and easy.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for all your help, truly appreciate it, but as a last thing, can you just have a look at my (and your combined tail-recursive) version, because I can't get the right output

Comment: `string-ref` yields a char so you really have to give up using strings in the first procedure. If you use `char-scorer` instead it will work.

Comment: sorry, i did do that, just forgot to update that part, which still gives me a value of -1 instead of -4

Comment: Nvmd, it is right, new .txt loaded, I owe you one, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, new to this, I did it, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

A syntactically correct version of what you have above is:

```
(define (string-scorer string1 string2)
  (cond ((equal? string1 string2) 2)
        ((or (equal? string1 "_" ) (equal? "_" string2)) -2)
        ((not (equal? string1 string2)) -1)
        (else 0))) ; ????
```

But I think you still have some confusion here. The first issue is that you specified in the comments thread that you are actually comparing strings rather than characters, so you need to use the string `"_"` rather than `#\_`. The second issue is that there are no conditions under which the `else` part of your conditional is reached. Once the first condition fails, we know that the two strings are not equal, so there is really no point in specifying the third condition as `((not (equal? string1 string2)) - 1)` when it could just as well be written `else -1`. A simpler version corresponding exactly to your spec would read:

```
(define (string-scorer string1 string2)  
  (cond ((equal? string1 string2) 2) 
        ((or (equal? string1 "_" ) (equal? "_" string2)) -2)
        (else -1)))
```

You can type in `(list (string-scorer "h" "h") (string-scorer "h" "k") (string-scorer "h" "_") (string-scorer "_" "h"))` to check it. *But* if there is some condition under which you want your function to return `0`, then you need to rethink your spec.

**Edit**: Here are some added functions that use the first one to score two multi-character strings, including when they are of different length (I assumed that the "extra" characters in the longer of the two strings would be counted as `-1`, since they are not aligned with any characters in the shorter string):

```
(define (string-head string1)
  (cond ((> (string-length string1) 0) (substring string1 0 1))
        (else "")))
(define (string-tail string1)
  (substring string1 1 (string-length string1)))
(define (string-scorer-2 string1 string2)
  (cond ((= (string-length string1) 0) (* -1 (string-length string2)))
        ((= (string-length string2) 0) (* -1 (string-length string1)))
        (else (+ (string-scorer (string-head string1)
                                (string-head string2))
                 (string-scorer-2 (string-tail string1)
                                (string-tail string2))))))
```

But you may want to just use some variant of uselpa's function, which is a lot more concise. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brian Fern, that helps a lot. But what if I wanted to use a longer string, then I won't get the correct answer. I've edited my code above to show you what I mean

Comment: Can we assume that the strings are the same length, or no?

Comment: Sorry, I mean, it doesn't have to be the same length

Comment: Thanks, but if i compare, for example 
"Hello" and "B_L_OW", i would rather add another underscore so that it reads
"Hello_" and "B_L_OW", giving me a score of -3